# MySQL JOIN performance on 1 big table and multiple small tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm planning to build a huge database. I already had a client before who had databases larger than 100M rows. So let's say we have a table A with 100M rows and have multiple tables with 250 rows.

I want to know which approach is faster usually (I know that it depends on a lot of things):

1. Join the small tables to the Large one based on IDs
2. Include the small table values in the large table

For example:

**1st Option:**

```
id  |   data1   |   data2   |   data3   |   table1_foreign_key  |   table2_foreign_key  |   table3_foreign_key
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   12                  |   34                  |   22
2   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   34                  |   67                  |   63
3   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   43                  |   34                  |   18
4   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   23                  |   21                  |   22
5   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   22                  |   34                  |   22
6   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   22                  |   34                  |   13
7   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   23                  |   54                  |   12
8   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   11                  |   57                  |   43
9   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   3                   |   34                  |   22
```

Here I would join all these small tables to the large one based on IDs. For example I'd store Cities, Countries, Devices, etc here.

**2nd Option:**

```
id  |   data1   |   data2   |   data3   |   table1_foreign_key  |   table2_foreign_key  |   table3_foreign_key
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Oklahoma            |   sample_text         |   sample_text
2   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   New York            |   sample_text         |   sample_text
3   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   New York            |   sample_text         |   sample_text
4   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   New York            |   sample_text         |   sample_text
5   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Washington          |   sample_text         |   sample_text
6   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Mitchigan           |   sample_text         |   sample_text
7   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Oklahoma            |   sample_text         |   sample_text
8   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Kansas              |   sample_text         |   sample_text
9   |   test    |   test    |   test    |   Dallas              |   sample_text         |   sample_text
```

In this second option there would be no JOINs but the data would be included here in the main large table. The expected data size per column would be something like 2-20 characters.

---

**Question:**

Which of the above options could be faster given that we have the same environment and have proper indexing? Which approach is advised here? (My customer wants to store clicks and click data in this database & tables.)

Comment: Do yourself and favor and run away screaming from option #2 as quickly as possible. What you have in the second option is not properly normalized. You are about to embark on what is known as "premature optimization". It is defined as making a non-standard design to deal with a performance problem that does not yet exist. It is pure evil.

Comment: What is the structure of your smaller tables? In order for option 2 to even work it appears each table would only have one column of data.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for this useful reply. So if I'm after reporting performance, it's still not even worth considering the 2nd option?

Comment: If you are after reporting performance then you should consider sending your data to a denormalized structure for reporting. It should not be the main source of your data. This is why cubes and other reporting structures are flattened, they are much faster for large quantities of data. But the main data is still properly normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a "one to many" relationship, I would store them in a separate table.  The SQL server query optimizer (under the hood) will be able to parse the 250 records quickly enough that it shouldn't be a concern.  Also, depending on the length of the values in the smaller table, you will be saving storage space by not storing them hundreds of millions of additional times.  However, if reporting performance is of the utmost importance, you can choose to store them in one "flattened" table - like a data warehouse structure, without the joins.  That will definitely be faster, but you would sacrifice storage space and your nicely-structured relational database.

All of that said, I would go with option 1.  But you should be able to easily store the data in a new table with the option 2 format - query against both of them - and then gauge the performance for yourself.  I expect that it won't be much of a difference, especially given the capacity of your smaller tables.

Comment: Perfect thank you, this clears up pretty much everything!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the second approach is definitely faster: basically, locating the record tends to be more expensive operation than its retrieval.

Although here are two things: first, obviously, you surrender your (related) data consistency enforcement; second, your particular case may not be that general to fit "generally speaking".

But whatever, denormalization like this is quite widely adopted nowadays.
Especially with what is called "NoSQL" solutions, but being treated with consciousness, it works for RDBMS too.

I would suggest you to:

1) Figure out your potential use cases regarding database usage, especially in scope of changes in related data, not only the query part

2) Arrange a PoC, implement both approaches & prove it with numbers.

Comment: Thanks for this as well, it's pretty useful also!